# Error: numeric or value errors

Tags: sql, oracle

I know this error issue was been addressed before, but I can't seem to find any relevant solution so I'm posting this question.

```
create table subscribers(
  num_s  number(6,0) ,  
  name varchar2(30)  constraint nameM not null, 
  surname varchar2(20), 
  town varchar2(30), 
  age number(3,0)  ,
  rate number(3,0) ,
  reduc number(3,0) ,
  CONSTRAINT subscriber_pk primary key (num_s),
  constraint age_c check (age between 0 and 120)
);

create or replace type copy_bookT as object(
  num               number(6),
  loancode          varchar2 (10),
  book_ref          ref bookT
);

create table copy_books of copy_bookT(
  constraint pk_cb primary key (num),
  constraint chk_st check (loancode in('Loan', 'Not')),
  loancode default 'Loan' not null
);


create table Lending(
  cb_num      number(6),
  sb_num      number(6),
  date_L      date,
  constraint fk_cb foreign key (cb_num) references copy_books(num),
  constraint fk_sb foreign key (sb_num) references Subscribers(num_s)
);



create or replace trigger chk_DateL
for insert or update on lending
COMPOUND TRIGGER
--declare
L_Date int;
avail varchar2(10);
subtype copy_booksRec is lending%ROWTYPE;
type copied_bks is table of copy_booksRec;
cbks copied_bks := copied_bks();

before each row is 
begin
  cbks.extend;
  cbks(cbks.last).cb_num := :new.cb_num;
  cbks(cbks.last).sb_num := :new.sb_num;
end before each row;

before statement is
begin
  for i in cbks.first .. cbks.last loop
    select loancode into avail from copy_books where num = cbks(i).cb_num;
    select count(date_L) into L_Date from lending where sb_num = cbks(i).sb_num and date_L = cbks(i).date_L;
      if (L_Date = 0 and avail = 'Loan') then
        update copy_books set loancode = 'Not' where num = cbks(i).cb_num;
        cbks.delete;
--        cbks(i).date_L := cbks(i).date_L;
    else
      dbms_output.put_line('You can only make ONE LOAN at a time! You have already loaned a book on ' || L_Date);
      cbks.delete;
    end if;
  end loop;
--  FORALL i IN cbks.first .. cbks.last
--      insert into lending values cbks(i);
    cbks.delete;
  end before statement;
end chk_DateL;
/
show errors
```

It all compiles successfully, but when I try to insert a sample record like:

```
insert into lending values (2, 700, '10-MAR-14');
```

it raises a numeric error which comes from the trigger line 18. I don't know what needs fixing despite my efforts.

Comment: That's the complete exact error message, "numeric or value errors"? Without ORA-##### code? And what line is line #18?

Comment: this is it- SQL Error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
Any suggestions would be appreciated. tnx

Answer (score 5):

You should not count on Oracle's default date format to translate your string literal to a `date` value , you should define the format you're using explicitly:

```
insert into lending values (2, 700, to_date('10-MAR-14', 'DD-MON-YY'));
```

Answer (score 3):

While the date format issue is a valid point, that isn't causing your error. It's coming from line 18, which is the `for ... loop` line:

```
before statement is
begin
  for i in cbks.first .. cbks.last loop
```

You've got `cbks` being extended and populated from the `before row` part of the trigger. When the `before statement` part fires, `cbks` is empty, as the row-level trigger hasn't fired yet. It's the `first` and `last` references that are throwing the `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error` error.

You can demonstrate the same thing with a simple anonymous block:

```
declare
  type my_type is table of dual%rowtype;
  my_tab my_type := my_type();
begin
  for i in my_tab.first .. my_tab.last loop
    null;
  end loop;
end;
/

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/22578); you can see you can avoid it by [adding an `extend`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/22579), but that doesn't really help you in your version, since you seem to want the row values. (You can eliminate the error in your code with an `extend`, but it's unlikely to do what you want still).

I'm really not sure what you're trying to achieve here, so I don't really have any advice on what you need to do differently.

Comment: hi Alex, my intention is too ensure that a subscriber doesn't make a loan more than once a day if not an error msg should be displayed. Also a book loan_code value has to be 'loan' before it can be taken. Meanwhile, i already hv the cbks table extended so ps what am i doing wrong? btw Seasons greetings...

Comment: @RalphBlackk - you do not already have `cbks` extended, that's the point. The statement-level trigger is firing and trying to use `cbks` before the row-level trigger has fired and extended it. This seems a really complicated approach. Why aren't ypu just using an intermediate table with subscriber, book and the loan date, with a unique constraint on person and date? And have other checks in a procedure that does the insert, maybe. Triggers aren't really suitable for this kind of thing, in my opinion. Also, why are you using objects for this at all?

Comment: the reason i rather use a trigger is so that i could change the constraint easily like for instance...to specify that a subscriber could loan a book not more than 5 times a day. A unique constraint won't do this u know? I already considered that option. Would the try work if i replaced the b4 stmt with after stmt?

Comment: i just replaced the before to after and rows get inserted but the trigger doesn't work. I don't know the sequence at which stmts fire btw b4 each row & after each row & before and after stmts? What order would best solve my problem? Oh my...

Answer (score 2):

as Mureinik already told, Oracle does not know about how to transform your varchar2 into date datatype and you should use date explicitly. But instead of making to_date use **date literal** - in my opinion it is more clear than using of to_date function

```
insert into lending values (2,700,date '2014-03-10');
```

by the way, you can simply change your NLS settings by altering the current session and installing the date format you need

Comment: +1 This also helps avoid month abbreviations, which depend on client settings.

Comment: the varchar2 literal isn't for the date select stmt. The date_L is an int literal for a count on a date column. Look at the select into stmts closely & u'll understand. I also doubt that counting a date result set raises an error. What say u?